# argparse: Subparser with global argument where position does not matter

Tags: python, argparse

I'll explain the problem with an example. Suppose we have the following code for a random python program:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="webduino-generator",
                                     description="Webduino source builder")
# Global arguments
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", 
                    action="store_true", dest='verbose',
                    help="Enable verbose output")


subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")

parser_build = subparsers.add_parser("build", help="Build it")
parser_open = subparsers.add_parser("open", help="Open it")

# Check arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Now with this parser, I can do

`program.py -v open`

which is great! However, I cannot do

`program.py open -v`

Also the parent/global argument `-v` will not be listed on the help page of the sub parser.

Is there a way to make this work and add it to the help page of the subparser?

Comment: Accepting the same argument in either/both the parent and sub is awkward.  You could define a `-v` argument in each of the subparsers - but I'd suggest given them a different `dest` parameter.  Both will appear in the `args`, and you can reconcile the values as you want. But that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Mhm, i expected as much. Ill go with arguments on subparsers only then. Thanks anyway!